# What is stc32ab IC

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

I have some `stc32ab` IC's but I cannot find any information or datasheet for them.

Please give me some information and/or datasheet about this IC

Comment: Is our google better than yours?

Comment: An ancient proverb says "Give a man a link and he has information for a day. Teach a man to Google, and he will have information for life." Or something like that about fish... idk...

Comment: @EugeneSh. I don't know about google but I hoped to face some better experience than mine!

Comment: @Tyler: I wonder that where the google's informations are come from!!

Answer (score 2):

To find an obscure part, you need more than the brief part number. Is there a manufacturer's logo?  What package is it?  What does it look like?  Where did it come from? Where/how is it used, etc. etc. etc.

It is also possible that it may be a "house number" and you will never find any information about it because it was never a product sold in the general market.

Very brief Googling revealed that there was a British company named Standard Telephones and Cables Ltd. (STC) who were a branch of the US company Western Electric who made most of the electronic gear for the first half of telephone history in North America.  The prefix "STC" and the very low sequence number (32) suggest that it might be one of their very early vintage parts.  Of course, since you did not provide a photograph (or even a physical description) we have no clue whether this is even a close guess.

Ref: http://www.wylie.org.uk/technology/semics/STC/STC.htm

Answer (score 2):

Small parts often don't have the whole part number on them, sometimes missing out characters in the middle which makes it hard to search for. They may also also include suffix characters which are not included in the base part number.

Some websites that specialize in electronic datasheets allow you to search on partial part numbers. [ALLDATASHEET.COM](http://www.alldatasheet.com) returns several possibilities when given the search string 'C32AB'.

A Google image search can sometimes give you clues. 'STC32AB' returns several chips with your number and the ST Microelectronics logo on them. If these images match your chips then you now know the manufacturer, and can narrow down the possibilities.

[image]

Comment: the only thing that i searched and find is that same chip that Bruce Abbott found.
in that case the chip's complete name is "ST26C32AB", and here is the datasheet:
http://datasheet.octopart.com/ST26C32ABDR-STMicroelectronics-datasheet-21332.pdf